# email tracking pixel for Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, tracking

I set a linked image 1x1 in HTML email and send it to a recipient for tracking open (if get image then email is opened). It works, but when I send an email, Gmail user just open their inbox (Not my email yet), then has a request to my server to get an image. So I don't track exactly this email is opened.
Is there any way to fix this error?
Here's my code:

```
<body>
<img height=1 width=1 src="https://example.com/email/v?u=123&aid=sds36gf3rik" style = "display:none" />
</body>
```

Many thank.

Comment: Hi and Welcome. To improve your experience on SO please take the tour, read how to ask and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve